# bpmn - simple test for JavaDelegate implementation

Tags: java, unit-testing, delegates, bpmn, camunda

I have implement a Simple JavaDelegate as a Task of my BPMN-Process:

```
public class CleanupVariables implements JavaDelegate {

    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
        String printJobId = execution.getVariable("VIP-Variable").toString();

        // remove all variables
        execution.removeVariables();

        // set variable
        execution.setVariable("VIP-Variable", printJobId);
    }
}
```

Now I want to write a Unit-Test.

```
 @Test
    public void testRemove() throws Exception {
        // Arrange
        CleanupVariables cleanupVariables = new CleanupVariables();

        testdelegate.setVariable("VIP-Variable", "12345");
        testdelegate.setVariable("foo", "bar");

        // Act
        cleanupVariables.execute(????); // FIXME what to insert here?

        // Assert
        Assertions.assertThat(testdelegate.getVariables().size()).isEqualTo(1);
        Assertions.assertThat(testdelegate.getVariable("VIP-Variable")).isEqualTo("12345");

    }
```

I could not figure out how to insert some implementation of `DelegateExecution` in my act-step. 
Is there any dummy-impl to use right here? How to test this as simple as possible?

I will not start a processinstance for testing this code. Google didn't come up with some usefull stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DelegateExecution` is an interface, so you can implement your own. But better option is to use some mocking library like mockito, which allows you to simulate only the method calls which you are interested in.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
...

DelegateExecution mockExecution = mock(DelegateExecution.class);
doReturn("printJobId").when(mockExecution).getVariable(eq("VIP-Variable"));
cleanupVariables.execute(mockExecution);
```

Here's a tutorial for mocking with mockito: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-series

Or maybe you can use `DelegateExecutionFake` which is in this package:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.extension.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>camunda-bpm-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But I cannot help with that since I've never used it.

Comment: Mocking this object in the given Testcase will be wrong in my opinion. If i do so the test will only test if i mocked everything correctly. It's sad, that camunda does not provide some dummy-implementation of this interface.

Comment: I don't think that's wrong, in unit test you want to test a single class only if possible.  But I've found some package with might help. I don't use it myself, but maybe it does what you are looking for.